# Всплытие блока там где произошел click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрытый блок iframe, который находится в body. 
На сайте есть проекты, у которых есть ссылка перехода на карточку проекта.
Но при клике на проект происходит ajax запрос, который передает страницу карточки в скрытый iframe. Iframe отсюда раскрывается плавно и заполняет всю страницу экрана. Всплытие начинается с центра экрана.
Вопрос.
Возможно ли сделать всплытие этого блока оттуда откуда произошел клик по проекту, то есть всплытие iframe начать с центра блока проекта а не с центра всего body.
Вот реализация моего кода

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".case_item_mob .case_link_<?php echo $post->ID ?>").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>",
      success: function(data){
        $("#frame").attr("src", "<?php the_permalink(); ?>");
        $('.iframe_project, #frame').css({
            'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
            'background-position':'center',
            'background-size':'cover',
            'position':'fixed',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'z-index':'100',
        });
        $('#frame').removeClass('animated zoomOut');
        $('#frame').addClass('animated zoomIn');
        $('.iframe_project, #frame').fadeIn();
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $('.close').fadeIn();
        history.pushState(null, null, '<?php the_permalink(); ?>');
      }
    });
});
$(".close").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#frame').removeClass('animated zoomIn');
    $('#frame').addClass('animated zoomOut');
    $('#frame, .iframe_project').fadeOut(2100);
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    $('.close').fadeOut();
    history.pushState(null, null, '/');
    setTimeout(function(){
        var frame = document.getElementById("frame"),
        frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
        frameDoc.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2100);                                   
});
```

});

Comment: можешь привести html код, а вообще через css все это можно указать

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае решением может послужить не просто менять src у iframe, а аппендить целиком iframe c нужным src в нужный блок

Comment: в srс у iframe задается ссылка которая грузится в нем. Сама анимация начинается с центра экрана. Если заносить iframe в блок, то он будет раскрываться в пределах этого блока. А мне нужно чтобы начало анимации происходило внутри блока далее заполнял всю область экрана.